# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\admin\ProductController::addToCart(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Hello I am making a cart but when I click on add to cart link then it says: "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\admin\ProductController::addToCart(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected", how can i sole this error error https://ibb.co/C2FZYD9
  Thanks in advance,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

model:

```
  <?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Cart
  {
private $contents;
private $totalQty;
private $contentsPrice;

public function __construct($oldCart){
    if ($oldCart) {
        $this->contents = $oldCart->contents;
        $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
        $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
    }
}

public function addProduct($product, $qty){
    $products = ['qty' => 0, 'price' => $product->price, 'product' => $product];
    if ($this->contents) {
        if (array_key_exists($product->slug, $this->contents)) {
            $product = $this->contents[$product->slug];
        }
    }

    $products['qty'] +=$qty;
    $products['price'] +=$product->price * $product['qty'];
    $this->contents[$product->slug] = $product;
    $this->totalQty+=$qty;
    $this->totalPrice += $product->price;
}

public function getContents()
{
    return $this->contents;
}
public function getTotalQty()
{
    return $this->totalQty;
}
public function getTotalPrice()
{
    return $this->totalPrice;
}
  }
```

routes:

```
  Route::get('cart', 'Admin\ProductController@cart')->name('product.cart');


  Route::get('/addToCart/{product}', 'Admin\ProductController@addToCart')->name('addToCart');
```

controller:

```
  public function cart()
{
    if (!Session::has('cart')) {
        return view('products.cart');
    }
    $cart = Session::has('cart');
    return view('product.cart', compact('cart'));
}

public function addToCart(Product $product, Request $request, $qty)
{
    if(empty(Auth::user()->email)){
        $data['email'] = '';    
    }else{
        $data['email'] = Auth::user()->email;
    }

    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
    $qty = $request->qty ? $request->qty : 1;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
    Session::put('cart', $cart);

    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Product $product->title has been successfully added to Cart');
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `addToCart()` function?

Comment: I think it's because of your route definition `Route::get('/addToCart/{product}', 'Admin\ProductController@addToCart');`, you only pass {product}

Comment: The `addToCart()` function expects 3 parameters. One is the request, and the others two are route params. Probably you miss one of them.

Comment: This is poor design... That should really be a `POST` request, and `productId` and `quantity` should be in the `$request` variable. Currently, you'd have to do a `GET` request to `/addToCart/{id}/{quantity}`, and that's just bizarre... Just define a `POST` route to `addToCart` and pass the correct values via input.

Comment: @zlatan   in route.….

Comment: @TimLewis get request isn't working

Comment: @MateusJunges  it wil be highly preferable if u tell me which I am missing

Answer (score 2):

This is your route:

```php
Route::get('/addToCart/{product}', 'Admin\ProductController@addToCart')->name('addToCart');
```

and your function definition:

```php
public function addToCart(Product $product, Request $request, $qty)
{
    // ...
}
```

This function expects the `$product` and `$qty` to be passed through your route.

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\admin\ProductController::addToCart(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected

This error means you only pass the product to the route.

Change the function definition or pass the parameter to the route and it will work.

**Update**
This is a small example, defining an option parameter to your `addToCart` function:

```php
public function addToCart(Product $product, Request $request, $qty=0)
{
    // ...
}
```

and for your route:

```php
Route::get('/addToCart/{product}/{qty?}', 'Admin\ProductController@addToCart')->name('addToCart');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I added it Route::get('/addToCart/{product}/{qty?}', 'Admin\ProductController@addToCart')->name('addToCart'); but still same

Comment: Check my update. I added an example with optional parameters.

Comment: Undefined property: App\Cart::$totalPrice            https://ibb.co/fCcwvXG

Comment: But does my solution fix your first error? I think you should open another question if it does, since this second one has nothing to do with this question scope.

Answer (score 0):

In your addToCart there are only two parameters passed so it searches for the third parameter in function addToCart. At mine this worked.

```
Route::get('/addToCart/{product}/{qty?}', 'Admin\ProductController@addToCart')->name('addToCart');
```

Comment: public function addToCart(Product $product, Request $request, $qty= null)

try this in your function putting $qty= null